# Phonegap JSON Build

Tags: javascript, ajax, phonegap, cordova

В PhoneGap Dev Работает все как часы. После сборки APK, getJSON и AJAX от jQuery работать перестали, возвращают статус "error".

Сервер возвращает в заголовке Access-Control-Allow-Origin *.

Локальные файлы те же методы грузят нормально.

config.xml:

```
  <access origin="*"/>
```

Один из методов:

```
 $.ajax
  dataType: 'jsonp'
  accept: 'application/jsonp'
  url: ContactsUploader.domain + '/data/lastupdate/'
  crossDomain: true
  success: (data)->
```

При событии onDeviceReady включаю поддержку CORS:

```
$.support.cors = true
```

В AndroidManifest доступ в сеть разрешил, на телефона приложение при установке их запросило:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: какое сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Сообщение NotFound

Comment: Собственно, с проблемой разобрался. Если собирать локально (CLI) - то тоже все работает. Скорее всего в phonegap build необходимо подписать сертификатом перед сборкой APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, с проблемой разобрался. Если собирать локально (CLI) - то тоже все работает. Скорее всего в phonegap build необходимо подписать сертификатом перед сборкой APK.